# Best practice to use @Configuration Bean in another @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to work with existing library of my company which has bunch of @Bean packaged in @Configuration in Spring project but would be added as dependency for my project. The situation would be similar to

```
@Configuration
Class A{
 @Bean
  B b(){
   return new B()
 }
}



@Configuration
  Class C{ 
    @Bean
    D d(){
     D d = new D();
   //TODO: How do I use instance of B here
     d.someConfiguration(B b);
     return d;
   }
  }
```

Should I initialized A using new operator in C and call method b or should I `@Autowire B` in C directly.

Comment: Just add it as an argument to the `d()` method, like `d(b b)` and Spring will resolve and inject it into the factory method for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this

**By field Autowiring**

```
@Configuration
 Class C{ 

 @Autowire
 private B b;

     @Bean
     D d(){
       D d = new D();
       //TODO: How do I use instance of B here
      d.someConfiguration(B b);
      return d;
      }
  }
```

**By constructor Autowiring** (Personally i prefer using constructor Autowiring which will be help during test cases)

```
@Configuration
 Class C{ 

 private B b;

  @Autowire
  public C(B b){
   this.b=b;
  }

     @Bean
     D d(){
       D d = new D();
       //TODO: How do I use instance of B here
      d.someConfiguration(B b);
      return d;
      }
  }
```

Or you can just add it as method arguments spring will resolve it

```
 @Configuration
 Class C{ 

     @Bean
     D d(B b){
       D d = new D();
       //TODO: How do I use instance of B here
      d.someConfiguration(B b);
      return d;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include the library sa a dependency, then when springboot initializes it scans the `@Configuration` files in those libraries as well. So the beans declared in those are already available in spring context.

So what you can do is just include it as a method parameter

```
@Configuration
  Class C{ 
    @Bean
    D d(B b){
     D d = new D();
     d.someConfiguration(b);
     return d;
   }
}
```

As soon as spring see that you want a bean if type B it will search and give u an instance.

I would say its evil to use `new` in spring :)